# Is there an AutoMinorLocator equivalent for matplotlib.dates?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to chart quote data with a datetime type using matplotlib.dates My challenge is I need the code to chart a range of time frames ranging from minutes per datapoint to a year per data point. I can use AutoDateLocator() for the major axis but I am struggling with a similar approach for the minor_locator (there is no AutoMinorLocator equivalent available for matplotlib.dates ... Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you will want to use `AutoDateLocator` for the minor ticks as well, just with a larger `minticks` value?

Comment: Yes - that was the right solution. As you pointed out - there is a need to use a larger minticks as without it the ticks will align (and had me scratching my head for a while). Thx ImportanceOfBeingEarnest!